# Get parent row from subgrid Jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is there any way to get the id of the parent row when clicking a button in the toolbar in a subgrid?

As of now, I can't use the custom button because I dont know which FK it should have..

I have tried the following, but it only returns the first row of the subgrid.

```
    var grid = $(this);
var currentRow = grid.jqGrid('getRowData', 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the name of the subgrid got the following name:
Jqgrid_PARENTID_t

So I ended up with extracting the value between the underscores with regex.